# Replacing non-alphabet characters from pandas column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Goal is to only keep the words and remove any non-alphabetical characters

I started with a column that containing strings within brackets

```
(Pdb) test['userTweets'].head()
0    [the SELU function to verify that the mean/variance is ~ 0/1...
1    [trump is really @#$#@%@#@$@#
2    [Yo Hillary! should have @*&(@#$@ Trump...
3    [When are we going to see those memos?????...
...
```

Since they contain bracket but not really a column containing list I did following to get rid of the brackets.

```
test['userTweets'] = test['userTweets'].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]')
```

Then I use python regex functionality:

```
(Pdb) regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
(Pdb) test['userTweets'] = test['userTweets'].str.replace(regex,'')
```

But I am getting `*** TypeError: object of type '_sre.SRE_Pattern' has no len()`

but regex is successfully build:

```
(Pdb) regex
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x11159f6a8>
```

Is there a better way to apply regex function to pandas string column to replace/remove any non-alphabetical characters?

Comment: Try passing the *string* pattern, not the regex compiled object. Also, add `regex=True` argument to Pandas `replace`

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
test['userTweets'] = "".join([c for c in test['userTweets'] if c in string.ascii_letters])
```

I've done something similar to the above.

Your code will probably look different but you get the general idea.